# Grouping columns based on pairwise equality

Tags: r, combinations

I have a matrix called equalityMatrix

```
> equalityMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]   29   29   29   29   55   55   55   55  101   101   101   111   111   115   134   134   134   151
[2,]  101  111  115  316  134  151  235  319  111   115   316   115   316   316   151   235   319   235
     [,19] [,20]
[1,]   151   235
[2,]   319   319
```

(Make yours:)

```
structure(c(29L, 101L, 29L, 111L, 29L, 115L, 29L, 316L, 55L, 
134L, 55L, 151L, 55L, 235L, 55L, 319L, 101L, 111L, 101L, 115L, 
101L, 316L, 111L, 115L, 111L, 316L, 115L, 316L, 134L, 151L, 134L, 
235L, 134L, 319L, 151L, 235L, 151L, 319L, 235L, 319L), .Dim = c(2L, 
20L))
```

This signifies that element 29 equals elements 101, 111, 115, and 316; that element 55 equals elements 134, 151, 235, and 319; and so on and so forth.

How do I efficiently obtain a list of equal elements like below?

```
[[1]]
[1] 29 101 111 115 316

[[2]]
[1] 55 134 151 235 319
```

I'll ultimately use the output of this command to create a mapping. These values are essentially indexes of elements that belong to the same group.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what you are doing to get the values into the list?

Comment: @rawr That would create a list with eight elements (one for each unique value in the first row of `equalityMatrix`). However I believe the OP wants just two elements in the list --- one for each set of five equal elements.

Comment: True. I'd have to remove the elements that are a subset of another- not a difficult task! Cheers!

Comment: @rawr The OP has left a few comments to that effect (on the question and on Richard's deleted answer), but you are correct that "and so on" implies more desired output. jackStinger, could you please update your question to clarify if you want more than two lines of output (as implied by "and so on") or exactly two lines of output in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to think of this would be as a graph, where each number is a node in the graph and two numbers co-occurring in a column mean the vertices associated with those two numbers share an edge in the graph. For your example, we could use the igraph package to create a graph with your data:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(t(equalityMatrix))
plot(g)
```

[image]

The components of the graph will be the numbers that are equal:

```
split(as.numeric(V(g)$name), components(g)$membership)
# $`1`
# [1]  29 101 111 115 316
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  55 134 151 235 319
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

equalityMatrix %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(c("group", "value")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(value = list(value))
```